# relative path of image doesn't work in pdfHTML, iText7 C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I credetd pdf using pdfHTML in iText7. I added image to the html file with the relative path as below.

```
<img src=/content/logo.jpg alt="logo" />
```

But the image doesn't print in the pdf. If I used full path of the image(C:/abc/content/logo.jpg), it is displayed in the document. Please help me to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: That is not a relative path because it starts with `/`.

Comment: Remove the `/` and show us how you create your converter properities: do you have this in your code: `ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties(); properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);` And if so, did you check if the value of `baseUri` is correct?

Comment: Thanks so much Bruno.   I haven't set the baseUri. Removed the / and asset the baseUri. Now it works. Display the image in the pdf.